# saving multiple sqlite3 db to documentsdirectory

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have an app in which I am trying to save several different tables to document directories. The first one saves fine, but the others do not. I've been researching and have not found anything that says I can't do this. Hopefully, someone can shed some light. The code I'm using is the typical "CreateEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded" but like I said, I have several versions of it depending on which db I'm trying to save. The code below is the 2nd one which does not work with "failure to open DB"
Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfScheduleDatabaseIfNeeded
  {
   //test if DB already exist
   BOOL success;
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   NSError *error;
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   //save new DB's
   NSString *writableScheduleDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"schedulelist.sqlite3"];
   NSLog(@"writable Schedule path:%@", writableScheduleDBPath);

   success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableScheduleDBPath];
   if (!success)
       NSLog(@"Failure to open Schedule DB");

   if (success) return;

   //the writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location
   NSString *defaultScheduleDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"schedulelist.sqlite3"];
   NSLog(@"default Schedule path:%@", defaultScheduleDBPath);

   success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultScheduleDBPath toPath:writableScheduleDBPath error:&error];
   if (!success)
       NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create Schedule writable database:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it runs first time it will display `NSLog(@"Failure to open Schedule DB");` as there is no database in document directory.

And yes mistake is in this line:

```
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultScheduleDBPath toPath:writableScheduleDBPath error:&error];
```

Just interchange arguments you are good to go.

Comment: not sure what happened, but after rebooting, everything seemed to be working. must have cleared out the doc directory.